# Spidermonkey: implementing "this"?

Tags: javascript, c++, spidermonkey, jsapi

I have spidermonkey setup to create objects from custom classes. For instance, in a script i can say...

```
var d0 = new MyDog();
```

...and on my app's C++ side a Dog object is created and stored.

What I would like to be able to do is then have that JSObject execute scripts in "it's own space". For example the dog object would execute a script that says...

```
this.Bark();
```

...and that dog object would call bark on itself.

With this functionality I could script objects independently.

I haven't found any info on this in the user guide documentation. I thought I could evaluate the script on the individual JSObject rather than the global object, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes. I went back through my code and although I was compile my scripts with the individual object's JSObject, I wasn't evaluating the script with it. Once I made that change I was able to execute scripts in an "individual object spaces".

So to be clear, if you want to execute scripts that operate on a single JSObject, evaluate it with that JSObject and not the global JSObject.